# React.js drag event causes a memory leak when changing state and references the new component as well as the old

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a timeline component where the goal is to drag an object downwards and create a new track row.

In order to achieve this, I am using a 2D array.

```
// first state (two items in the same row)
const exampleShape = [[{1: {stack: 1}}, {2: {stack: 1}}]]

// second state (two items in their own row)
const exampleShape = [[{1: {stack: 1}}, {2: {stack: 2}}]]
```

Then I use React to render the UI accordingly. The problem is I am updating the state as a drag event is happening when the drag is still active (aka the mouse is still clicked) the event listener is still alive.

The state is updated as the event is alive and the component is remounted. I think the event gets re-registered to the new referenced component and now both components are being referenced.

My question is how can I improve this code to avoid the issue?
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sea-f6031?file=/src/App.js:631-648

I've also shot a video to explain this issue more clearly and how to recreate the issue inside the sandbox
https://www.loom.com/share/e7aeda07d81f488eb9a7aafbc6fc8dd1

I think this will be interesting. Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: interestingly it's only on the first drag; i.e. dragging Fake 2 down, and then back up and down again and you will only get the error once

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly weird. I wonder if adding a new one causes another error because it creates a new listener reference. I think it goes away because the references exist. Just tested it and it doesnt. I've isolated it somewhat, but still am confused.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove all event listeners on all the child components on unmount?

Comment: I notice the error originates from `Draggable` - I looked at the issues of `react-rnd` and this has come up before, but not sure if it matches your scenario

Comment: I have a solution in the works that I plan to share soon. It involves using the mouseMove event.